# How to get the value using 'http.uri.params' in mule

Tags: mule, uri, parameters

I am trying to get the value through URI params in mule. I am using

```
`#[message.inboundProperties.'http.uri.params'.Id]`
```

to get the value. When I pass a value, (for eg 16) it is returning as `Id=16`. Since I am passing this value into a database stored procedure, I need the value alone. Could anyone help me out in this.

Comment: It would help to have the listener path you are defining to get that URI param and the request you are sending.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me in Mule 3.7.3:

```
<http:listener-config name="listener2" host="0.0.0.0" port="8083"/>
<flow name="uri">
    <http:listener path="uri/{param}/resource" config-ref="listener2" />
    <expression-transformer expression="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.uri.params'.param]" />
</flow>
```

Running `curl http://127.0.0.1:8083/uri/value/resource` returns `value` which is the expected according to [the documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/http-listener-connector).

Comment: I am not passing the value as a query parameter. Instead I pass it as a uri parameter.

Answer (score 0):

What about storing "id=16" as a string variable and splitting it on the =?

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
#[message.inboundProperties.'http.uri.params'[0]['Id']
```

will retrieve only the value of the id. This will surely work.

Comment: The expression is not correctly terminated. And why the [0]?